# vectorize nested for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, mapply

First of all, this is not a HW problem. I've been using nested for loops when I was in school because they work fine with the size of data I dealt with. However now my job requires dealing with fairly big data size and I tried to run loops but they would take days to finish. So I'm just wondering how I can apply 'mapply' to nested for loop.

Basically I'm running some text matching in R and what I did was to use

```
match_1=table1[,1]
match_2=table2[,1] 
match_split_1 <- str_split(match_1, pattern = " ")
match_split_2 <- str_split(match_2, pattern = " ")
k = 1
match_result=matrix("empty",ncol=26,nrow=500)
for (i in length(match_split_1))
{
   for (j in length(match_split_2))
{
       if (identical(match_split_1[[i]],match_split_2[[j]]))
{
        temp_result <- c(table1[i,], table2[j,])

      match_result[k,] <- t(as.matrix(c(k,temp_result)))
   k=k+1
   #I tried to pre allocate a matrix to match_result and not increase size
   #of it everytime. However I received: Error in match_result[k, ] <-  
   #t(as.matrix(c(k, temp_result))) : 
   #  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix


}


}
```

Any insight?
thanks!

Update: here is a more concrete example:

table1:

```
name   score  address 
 Jason   8      10 Cornell Street 
 Lisa    7     110 Park Avenue    
 David   10     225 Fifth Avenue
```

Table 2:

```
name    phone# 
David   323-4527 
Kudrow  233-3618
```

So I'm trying to match these two tables by name and I can't just join them because the matching I'm doing is fuzzy. There are always punctuations, blanks, upper/lower letter etc that I need to deal with.
What I'm doing is to extract name from each of the table and do fuzzy matching with a nested for loop (the loop is shown in above). then I use the index i, j to combine a row then append it to 'match_result'. Now I'm wondering if I can replace the nested loops with vectorization.

Thanks!

Comment: First suggestion is to not 'grow' objects by successively rbinding: see chapter 2 of the [Burns Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: Provide a concrete problem with all inputs and expected output.

Comment: Typically one would use `merge` but offering an example is impossible with such a sketchy description that obviously is pseudo code. There is are text mining algorithms in pkg:tm and regular expressions are reasonable well-integrated into R although there are some language-specific quirks that one needs to master. Use the edit feature to improve this question.

Comment: Thanks for all the comment! I'm trying to pre allocate my match_result to a matrix and see how it goes. But still no idea on how to vectorize it

Comment: The vectorization that needs to happen is to vectorize `some criterion for matching`. If you can't be more specific than that, there's nothing more we can do to help you.

Comment: Hi Gregor, thanks for your comment. please see the updated with more specifics.